# Icon Files for iOS app

Tags: ios, icons

I was reading http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html, how does Xcode know when to display a particular icon. Is it based on the name or the resolution?

Answer (score 2):

It's based on a couple things but primarily the file name. You also need to specify what's what based on the info.plist.

If the resolution is wrong, xcode will throw a warning, though.

This page shows all the various sizes but needs to be updated for iPad retina: http://mrgan.tumblr.com/post/708404794/ios-app-icon-sizes

Good luck!